# AWS - SQS concurrency

Tags: amazon-web-services, concurrency, amazon-sqs

a little question about SQS message concurrency.

**scenario**:
i created lambda with 3 minute timeout.
this lambda triggered by SQS service (with default configuration).

when SQS trigger my lambda he waiting X second (under 3 minute).
after waiting, he run the same lambda again.

now, i have two lambdas run in the same time.

for this case, in the end - lambda_1 is failed and lambda_2 Succeeded.

**the question**:
the SQS message is remove from the queue?

lambda which Succeeded deletes the message from queue.
lambda which failed do retry for this message.

**and how can i control concurrency issue?**

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQS message to be removed from the queue, lambda has to explicitly [delete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/delete-message.html) it from the queue upon successful processing. (<- this is incorrect, see the edit below).

If lambda fails while processing the message, the message will be returned to the queue when [message visibility](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html) timeout finishes (default is 30 seconds). Thus, it will have a chance to be processed again by lambda.

In your SQS queue settings, you can setup [Dead-Letter Queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html) to store messages that failed to be processed successfully for number of tries.

Edit:

As @michael-sqlbot correctly pointed out, the first part on my answer was incorrect. When your function successfully processes a batch, Lambda deletes its messages from the queue.

To control lambda concurrency use [Reserved Concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) setting.

Comment: OK, thanks. for my understood, if SQS wake up two same lambda with same message from the queue (with 30 (+-) second delay from thus lambda). if one lambda success and one failed, the message still be in the queue because the failed lambda. or i am confusing and it is not same message? (different id?)

Comment: @בני   SQS will not normally invoke two functions for same message (duplicate messages can happen though rarely). Entire purpose of SQS is to have one producer and one consumer for individual messsages.

Comment: @בני No problem. If so, accepting the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @Marcin the first part is incorrect.  The Lambda function does not need to delete the message.  If the invocation finishes without throwing an exception, the messages in the batch are deleted from the queue. The only time you need to delete messages from code is if you are batching n > 1 messages and you want to succeed on some and fail on others within the same function invocation.  [*"When your function successfully processes a batch, Lambda deletes its messages from the queue."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) "Lambda" means the Lambda service, not the function.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks. I editted the answer accordingly.